# UWP handling many threads

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

So I am developing a UWP application that has a large number of threads. Previously I would start all the threads with `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run()`, save their thread handles to an array, then `Task.WaitAll()` for completion and get the results. This currently is taking too much memory though.

I have changed my code to only wait for a smaller amount of threads and copy their results out before continuing on to more of the threads. Since UWP the UWP implementation of Task does not implement IDisposable, what is the proper way to signal the framework that I am done with a task so it can be garbage collected? I would like to read out the results of the treads after a certain number of them come in and dispose of the threads resources to make space for the next threads.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to point out an issue which might be degrading the performance of your application: You are deliberately blocking the thread until all Tasks complete rather than actually await for them. That would make sense, if you are not performing Asynchronous work inside them, but if you are, you should definitely switch to:

`Task.WhenAll` rather than `Task.WaitAll` , such as this:

```
List<Tasks> tasks = new List<Tasks> { Method1(), Method2(), ... };
Task result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This way, you are actually leveraging the asynchrony of your app, and you will not block the current thread until all the tasks are completed, like `Task.WaitAll()` does.

Since you are utilizing the `Task.Run()` method, instead of the `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, the TaskScheduler used is the default, and utilizes Threads from the Thread Pool. So you will not actually end up blocking the UI thread, but blocking many Thread Pool threads, is also not good.

Taking from Microsoft documentation, for one of the cases where Thread Pools should not be used:

> You have tasks that cause the thread to block for long periods of
>   time. The thread pool has a maximum number of threads, so a large
>   number of blocked thread pool threads might prevent tasks from
>   starting.

**Edit:**

> I do not need anything else but I will look in to that! Thanks! So is
>   there any way I can get it to run the Tasks like a FIFO with just the
>   API's available with the default thread pool?

You should take a look, into [Continuations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks)

A `continuation` is nothing else other than a task which is activated whenever it's antecedent task/tasks have completed. If you have specific tasks which you only want to execute after another task has completed you should take a look into Continuations, since they are extremely flexible, and you can actually create really complex flow of Tasks to better suit your needs.

Comment: So you are saying I should switch to a task factory with my own custom TaskScheduler?

Comment: @KennyWitham No! Maybe I didn't word correctly, but I actually meant that you were doing the right thing by utilizing the Task.Run() method. 
My main question mark is if you are doing asynchronous work on the thread! If you are, you should utilize Task.WhenAll for sure ...

Comment: I do not need anything else but I will look in to that! Thanks! So is there any way I can get it to run the Tasks like a FIFO with just the API's available with the default thread pool? Basically I am generating thousands of task but the thread pool is not completing them in order they are started so I cannot release any threads until they all complete

Comment: Edited my answer, which describes a feature of TPL which allows customization of the tasks flow, allowing for example to chain tasks one after another to any arbitrary length, which seems to suit your needs.

Comment: I am actually using the TAP pattern already for my algorithm. your suggestion pointed me in the right direction to the page for that: [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/consuming-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern). I think I can use the throttling section for my needs! I originally decided on TAP because of my need for progress reporting. Is there a reason I should change to using TPL?

Comment: Glad I could help (even if somehow inadvertently haha). But yes throttling, seems like a good measure for your case. As far as I know TPL, I would guess TPL is more suited to Parallel programming, but I don't think it differs significantly from TAP.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection on a .Net application always works the same, when a variable is not needed anymore (out of scope) it is collected.

Why do you think the threads are consuming the memory? It is much likely than the process inside the threads is the one consuming the memory.

Comment: As the threads start to execute the memory consumption of my application does not stop growing on the order of GB which is not the amount of data I have. After the thread completes and I read the `Task.Result` from the task handle the thread is not released from memory though even though I no longer need it to be saved. Is there a way to signal that I am done with the results and the runtime can trash my thread?

Comment: It's not about the thread, the issue is most probably about what the thread executes. If you do all the work on a single thread I bet that you will end with the same memory consumption.